# Помогите отредактировать субтитры к мультфильму "Домовой и Хозяйка"

Tags: лексика

Извините, я очень плохо знаю по-русский, но помогите пожалуйста пополнять следующий транскрипт за мультик Домовой и Хозяйка (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GBA5rkVwU7c)

— Ах как прекрасно вас ... Ты прекрасно ...

— Ах, тётушка, какой ... и какой ...

— Наконец-то у меня есть кем поговорить о поезии!

— Всё это ... и вздор. Женщины должна уметь варить кашу.

— Хм, домовой же нет, не иначе.

— ... при гости, не поговори глупости. Домовой! Домовой – это понятие!

— Дядушка, а вы верите в домовых ?

— Чего только не бывает на свете!

— Домовых нет! И быть не может! А это – это ветер ...

— Позвольте мне ... окно ...

— ...

— Опять приехал наши сливки ...

— За каждый ... сморети надо!

— Вот так-так ...хозяюшка ... вот так-так ... ... на здоровье. Что ты теперь сказешь, госпожа ... ? Нет домовых ? А ?

— ... тебе никогда не видела.

— ... а видеть ... за чем ? Кто вчера разбил её чернила ? Кто собаку по ночам ... ? А кто тебя ...

— Почему не пролизает ? Вот, смотри!

— Мышки! ... мыши! ... надо тебя ...

— У плохой хозяйке всегда кот виноват!

— Страдание ...

— Страдание ... ... А это надо записать!

— Поезия мой дом родной! Поезия! Кто здесь ? Что вы здесь делаете в полночи ?

— Я потерял очки!

— Не беда! Я прочту вам свои стихи сама. Поезия, мой дом родной, а в нём хозяин ... ... ...

— Обо мне ?

— Благослови ...мой домовой. Мой ...

— Тётушка, ваше стихотворение ...

— ... как я ... несправедлив ...

— Как вы ... к поезии ...

— А как она умна! Как образованна! А ну брысь отсюда!

— Что это с тобой ?

— ... не спим ... гениальные стихи сочиняем ... сливки ...

— ... ...

— ... отсюда показал! Обо мне скоро весь свет обознает! А сливки – я тебе сам буду ...

Answer (score 3):

— Ах, как прекрасна в воскресном уборе земля!.. Ты прекрасна в воскресном уборе, земля.

Милые дали, шельфы, леса и поля. Экспромт!

— Ах, тётушка, какой слог! И какое знание географии! Леса, поля!

— Наконец-то у меня есть с кем поговорить о поэзии!

— Всё это чушь и вздор. Женщина должна уметь варить кашу.

— Хм, домовой шалит, не иначе.

— Умоляю, хотя бы при госте не поговори глупости. Домовой! Домовой — это понятие!

— Дядюшка, а вы верите в домовых?

— Чего только не бывает на свете!

— Домовых нет! И быть не может! А это? Это ветер шальной колобродит в ночи. Это ветка ольхи к нам в оконце стучит…

— Позвольте мне закрыть слуховое окно.

— Очкарик.

— Опять приехал наши сливки лакать.

— За кашей-то смотреть надо!

— Вот так-то, хозяюшка! Вот так-то! Лакай, лакай на здоровье. Что ты теперь скажешь, госпожа поэтесса? Нет домовых? А?

— Да ведь она тебя никогда не видела.

—  А видеть-то зачем? Кто вчера разбил её чернила? Кто собаку по ночам дразнит? А кто тебя раскормил? Вон морда в кувшин не пролезает.

— Почему не пролезает? Вот, смотри!

— Мышь! В кладовой мыши! Ах ты, его надо сейчас же выпороть.  Вот тебе, вот тебе, вот тебе! Иди, иди... Ой...

— У плохой хозяйки всегда кот виноват!

— Ну! Страданье ниспослано нам для смиренья.

— Страданье ниспослано мне для смиренья. Ах! В страдании черпаю своё вдохновение. Это надо записать!

— Поэзия — мой дом родной! Поэзия… Ой, кто здесь? Что вы здесь делаете ночью?

— Я потерял очки!

— Не беда! Я прочту вам свои стихи сама. Поэзия — мой дом родной, а в нём хозяин — дивный строй летучих рифм, что надо мной имеют сладостную власть. Как в аллегорию не впасть? Как не назвать сей шумный рой, мне досаждающий порой, старинным словом «домовой».

— Обо мне?

— Благослови сию обитель, мой домовой. Мой повелитель.

— Тётушка, ваше стихотворение пробуждает столько мыслей.

— Ах, как я был к ней несправедлив.

— Ах, как вы тонко разбираетесь в поэзии.

— А как она умна! Как образованна! А ну брысь отсюда!

— Что это с тобой?

— Мы с госпожой ночей не спим. Мы гениальные стихи сочиняем.  А ты наши сливки лакать?!

— Эх, стоило хозяйке мяукнуть польстивее...

— Убирайся отсюда, пока цел! Обо мне скоро весь свет узнает! А сливки я теперь сам буду пить.

Comment: Очень спасибо вам! Я благодарю вас! ❤

Comment: @Третийглаз Проделана большая работа! Но есть, правда, пара-тройка замечаний. 1. _Наконец-то у меня есть, с кем поговорить о поэзии!_ Запятая в неразложимом сочетании не нужна. (https://orfogrammka.ru/%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9/) 2. _А это — это ветер шальной колобродит в ночи._ Думаю, лучше так: А это? Это ветер... 3. А кто тебя раскормил? 4. _— Убирайся отсюда пока цел!_ Нужна запятая перед "пока".

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова спасибо, исправил.